# Extensions Functions From POCO Classes In Saxon-HE For .NET

Tags: .net, xslt, saxon

The built-in .NET XsltArgumentList allows us to register POCO classes containing methods that will be available as XSLT functions.
Is there a similar mechanism for Saxon-HE? I know about ExtensionFunctionDefinition and ExtensionFunctionCall, but this is not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest equivalent is "reflexive extension functions", described here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility/dotnetextensions

But this requires Saxon-PE or higher.